# Using each() with ajax() done() processing ajax synchronously

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have read many different posts about how to use done() with $.ajax().  As I understand it, ajax returns a promise so the done() should be executed on completion, which seems to be happening, however when in an each() loop, once the first ajax function is reached, the 2nd loop initiates while the first loop is still processing.

Here is a basic jsfiddle of the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/kLja50xa/1/

My desired result is:

`1-1
2-1
1-2
2-2`

I have tried the option to push the requests to an array, but this means more nestsed each() ajax() loops with the same issue?

The reason I need to process these in order is that some instances within the loop require user input.

I can force the required result using `async:false`. but for obvious reasons I want to avoid this.  Also this has additional impacts to the script whereby I cannot target and update a tracking message advising the user where the process is.

Comment: If you want to enforce ordering, then you can't just fire all asynchronous requests at once.

Comment: @Phylogenesis - I do not want to fire them all at once, which is why I am using the done() to fire the next request once the result of the first one have been received.  Do you have a suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is possible with a loop.... try using a function that will call it self once the ajax is done

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/7rup0794/)

eachArray(array);

```
function eachArray(array){
    $i++;
  console.log('1-'+$i);
    ajax.done(function() {
    console.log('2-'+$i);
    if($i<array.length){
        eachArray(array);
    }
  })
}
```

Another ES6 cool feature will be using [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) is actually a function that pauses its code until you called again

Comment: Fantastically simple! Thanks you!